# What is the reason behind different vector initiations as a class member vs within a method?

Tags: c++

I was trying to under the logic behind the C++ design. Here is my question. 
In the following codes, why I can't initiate it as a class membership,

> vector fhd(10);

but I can initiate it in a method

> vector abc(10);

Will the first way cause any confusion for the compiler?

Here is the complete codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class testVector{

private:
    int vl;
 //error reported below
    vector<int> fhd(10);
public:
    testVector(int vl){
        this->vl=vl;
    }

    vector<int> assVal(){
        //OK below
        vector<int> abc(10);

        cout << "haha" << endl;
        for(int iter=0; iter < vl; iter++){
            fhd.push_back(iter);
        }
        return fhd;
    }

    void showVec(){
        for(int iter=0; iter < fhd.size(); iter++){
            cout<< fhd[iter] << endl;
        }
    }


};

int main() {


    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    testVector cj(5);

    cj.assVal();
    cj.showVec();
    return 0;
}
```

What's the logic behind that we can't do that? I understand that there are some alternative way to do it as a class member, such as

```
vector<int> fhd = vector<int>(10);
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: You might use `vector<int> fhd = vector<int>(10);` since C++11.

Comment: I understand this. But why it doesn't allow to initiate it as within a method? What's the logic behind of C++ development?

Comment: To avoid any possibility of recreating the most vexing parse fiasco. There are duplicates out there, but I can't seem to find them right now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the vector to have a fixed size of 10? If so then you might prefer

```
std::array<int, 10> fhd;
```

If you want it to be a vector, then you can give it a default value using syntax like

```
vector<int> fhd = std::vector<int>(10);
```

Comment: I understand this. But why it doesn't allow to initiate it as within a method? What's the logic behind of C++ development? Many thanks!